# Keeping Dynamic Table Rows shown after form post errors

Tags: php, jquery

I have a dynamic HTML table that allows users to enter receipt items in, and they can add as many rows as necessary.

If they forget to fill out a field upon form POST, I want all those rows with the data to stay shown, instead what happens, is they dynamic rows disappear and no values are saved in the one row that shows on default.

How can I achieve having those dynamic table rows shown with the values they've entered to avoid them having to enter all the data again?

```
 <?php
 if(isset($saveAdd))
{
$expenseType = safeDataMySQL($_POST['expenseType']);

//Save page, redirect to same page but increment receipt number.
if(empty($_POST['expenseNumber']))
    {
    //New expense so no records have been created as of yet. Otherwise, this would be stored in hidden field.
    $getRef = mysql_query("SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(refNumber,4) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS referenceNumber  FROM expense_main ORDER BY referenceNumber DESC LIMIT 1") or die("Ref No: " . mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($getRef) > 0)
        {
        while($refData = mysql_fetch_array($getRef))
            {
            //Expense Number!
            $refNumber = $refData['referenceNumber'];
            $refNumber = ($refNumber + 1);
            }

        $ins = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `expense_main` (`respid`, `refNumber`, `dateCreated`, `draftMode`, `expenseType`) VALUES ('".$respid."', 'USA".$refNumber."', NOW(), '1', '".$expenseType."')") or die("Expense Insert: " . mysql_error());

        $expClaimNumber = 'USA'.$refNumber;
        }
    }

else
    {
    $expClaimNumber = safeDataMySQL($_POST['expenseNumber']);
    }

//Get the next receipt in line as well
$getRec = mysql_query("SELECT receiptNumber FROM expense_details ORDER BY receiptNumber DESC LIMIT 1") or die("Get Receipt: " . mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($getRec) > 0)
    {
    while($recData = mysql_fetch_array($getRec))
        {
        $receiptNumber = $recData['receiptNumber'];
        $receiptNumber = ($receiptNumber + 1);
        }
    }

$fields = array('recLineDate_', 'recLineCategory_', 'recLineDescr_', 'recLineAmount_');

foreach ($fields as $field) 
    {
    foreach ($_POST[$field] as $key=>$line) 
        {
        $returnArray[$key][$field] = $line;                             
        }
    }

foreach ($returnArray as $lineItem) 
    {
    if(empty($lineItem['recLineDate_']))
        {
        $Errors[] = 'You forgot to enter the receipt date.';
        }

    else
        {
        $recDate = safeDataMySQL($lineItem['recLineDate_']);
        }

    if(empty($lineItem['recLineCategory_']))
        {
        $Errors[] = 'You forgot to enter a category.';
        }

    else
        {
        $recCategory = safeDataMySQL($lineItem['recLineCategory_']);
        }

    if(empty($lineItem['recLineDescr_']))
        {
        $Errors[] = 'You forgot to enter a description.';
        }

    else
        {
        $recDescr = safeDataMySQL($lineItem['recLineDescr_']);
        }

    if(empty($lineItem['recLineAmount_']))
        {
        $Errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your receipt amount.';
        }

    else
        {
        $recAmount = safeDataMySQL($lineItem['recLineAmount_']);
        }

    if(empty($_POST['alternateBranch']))
        {
        $alternateBranch = '0';
        }

    else
        {
        $alternateBrach = $_POST['alternateBranch'];
        }

    if(!isset($Errors))
        {
        $recDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($recDate));

        $ins = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `expense_details` (`receiptNumber`, `claimId`, `alternateBranch`, `dateAdded`, `expenseDate`, `expenseDescription`, `expenseAmount`, `categoryId`) 
                        VALUES ('".$receiptNumber."', '".$expClaimNumber."', '".$alternateBranch."', NOW(), '".$recDate."', '".$recDescr."', '".$recAmount."', '".$recCategory."')") or die("Could not insert receipt: " . mysql_error());

        $nextReceipt = ($receiptNumber + 1);

        //Redirect to same page, incrementing the receipt number by 1.
        header('Location: createExpense.php?expenseNumber='.$expClaimNumber.'&receiptNum='.$nextReceipt);
        }
    }
}

 $expenseNumber = safeData($_GET['expenseNumber']);
 $receiptNumber = safeData($_GET['receiptNum']);

 if (isset($Errors))  
{
echo "<div align='center'><span class='errormessagered'><ul class='errors'>";
foreach ($Errors as $Error) 
    {
    echo "<li>".$Error."</li>";
    echo '<br />'; 
    }
echo "</ul></span></div>";
}
   ?>

<form name="createNew" method="POST" action="">
<div id="row">
<div id="left">
    <strong>Receipt Items:</strong>
</div>
<div id="right">
    <i>Only add another line to the receipt below IF you have multiple items on one receipt.</i>
    <br /><br />
    <table border="0" width="825px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" name="receipts" id = "receipts">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="colheader" width="120px">Date</th>
                <th class="colheader" width="120px">Category</th>
                <th class="colheader" width="120px">Description</th>
                <th class="colheader" width="120px">Amount</th>
                <th class="colheader" width="145px"><span class="boldblacklinks"><a href="#" id="add">[Add +]</a></span></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
            <tbody class="lineBdy">
                <tr id="line_1" class="spacer">
                    <td><input type="text" class="date fieldclasssm" id="recLineDate[]" name="recLineDate_[]" size="10" value = "<?=date("m/d/Y", strtotime($today))?>"/></td>
                    <td><select name="recLineCategory_[]" class="fieldclasssm">
                                <option value = "">Select a Category...</option>
                                <?php //Get Categories

                                $getCats = mysql_query("SELECT id, nominalName FROM expense_nominalCodes ORDER BY id") or die("Get Cats: " . mysql_error());

                                if(mysql_num_rows($getCats) > 0)
                                    {
                                    while($catData = mysql_fetch_array($getCats))
                                        {
                                        echo '<option value = "'.$catData['id'].'"'; if($catData['id'] == $_POST['recLineCategory_']) { echo "Selected = 'SELECTED'"; } echo '>'.$catData['nominalName'] . '</option>';
                                        }
                                    }
                                ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="lineDescr fieldclasssm" name="recLineDescr_[]" id="recLineDescr[]" value = "<?=$_POST['recLineDescr']?>" size="40" /></td>
                    <td colspan = "2"><input type="text" class="sum lineAmount fieldclasssm" name="recLineAmount_[]" id="recLineAmount[]" value = "<?=$_POST['recLineAmount']?>" size="12" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

" />
      " />

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function () {
  $('.date').change(function () {
  $('.date').val($('.date:nth-of-type(1)').val());
  });
  });

  //Add new table row & clone date field
  $('#add').on('click', function(){
  addReceiptItem();
  $('.date').focus(function() {
  $(this).select();
  });
        $('.receipt').focus(function() {
  $(this).select();
  });

     });

        function addReceiptItem(){
        var lastID = $('tr[id*="line_"]').length,    
         newTds = $('tr[id="line_' + lastID + '"] td').clone(),
         newRow = document.createElement('tr');

        // add new id and class to row, append cloned tds
        $(newRow)
        .attr('id', 'line_' + (lastID + 1 ))
        .attr('class', 'spacer')
        .append(newTds);

        $(newRow).find('input').not(':eq(0)').val('');
        // $(newRow).find('class').not(':eq(0)').not(':eq(0)').val('');

        //add the new row to the table body
        $('tbody.lineBdy').append(newRow);
        $('.receipt').attr('readonly', true);
        $('.date').attr('readonly', true);
        };
        </script>
```

Comment: How are you calling your save function?

Comment: Each time a row is created, you could create a hidden input with the data, then recall this on the failed save. `<input type='hidden' name='rows[]' value='delimited,string,of,row,values' />` Then when the save fails, just loop through `$_POST['rows']` to generate those rows again.

Comment: I don't have a save function.

Answer (score 0):

Just to get you started. You can add the rows from $_POST["rows"]

```
foreach ($_POST["rows"] as $rowstring) {
    list($date, $cat, $desc, $amt) = explode(",", $rowstring)

    ?>
    <td><?php echo $date; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $cat; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $desc; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $amt; ?></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>    
    <?php
}
```

Assuming you add a hidden input with a comma delimited string each time a dynamic row is added.

FWIW, I would also recommend doing all of the database queries (ie $getCats = ...) prior to rendering anything to the screen so that in case the 'or die()' happens, you wont get a half rendered page.